# why this error is coming "com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException"

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am working with google drive app storage and that is working fine in debug apk as well as release apk but once I upload that apk to play store and then if download from play store this feature stop working.

I have tried to put some toast in catch to understand why this issue is coming then I know this below error is coming

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
```

I had google but not help in my case.

Comment: this link may help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526658/googleauthexception-unknown-when-authenticating-with-cloud-endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526658/googleauthexception-unknown-when-authenticating-with-cloud-endpoints)

Comment: @z85510 read not work for me

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, i did read some posts and was able to get work done by following below steps

Step 1) Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?

Step 2) Click on create credentials ->select OAuth client ID ->select application type as Android

Step 3) then generate Signing-certificate fingerprint by writing below command in command prompt before that you should have keystore and its path

```
 keytool -exportcert -keystore "D:\PlayStore_keystore\myproject.jks" -list -v
```

Step 4) after click on enter you will be asked for

```
 Enter keystore password : 
 Enter password which you have used for creating keystore
```

Step 5) then it will give details regarding keystore like SHA1,SHA256,MD5 etc.

Step 6) Enter SHA1 as fingerprint and give packagename which is in manifest file

step 7) Click create you will get new OAuth client ID

step 8) now you have got client id you will need to get google-services.json file.

step 9) please goto https://console.firebase.google.com

step 10) if you already have project with that packagename ->go to overview ->click on menu icon where packagne name is written

step 11) select settings goto-> tab General-> there will be option called Add fingerprint

step 12) in step 5 you have got SHA1 paste that in certificate fingerprint and save it

step 13) now download new google-services.json file (as it conatins new client id ,certificate_hash etc)

step 14) paste that google-services.json file in app folder in your android project.

step 15) You are good to go...

Comment: Are you sure this will help me bcz I am alread using firebase and and have already make OAuth client ID with release keystore key sha1 in both places.

Comment: When you update your app to play store, Google uses replaces the signing keys, so you have to use them.