# Youtube Data Api Not Working in Release APK when Hosted on PlayStore

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

Hi I used YouTube Data API V3 in one of My Android App I have tested it in both **Debug APK and And Release APK** in both are Working Fine but when I hosted that Release APK in Play Store then it show me  GoogleAuthIOException.[image: Please Refer Image that I got Exception]. Please provide me with the solution with the reason why this happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092511/why-this-error-is-coming-com-google-api-client-googleapis-extensions-android-gm

Comment: @Arahasya I already done this but not getting What happens when I host that APK on play store. When I test that release APK before hosting on play store it works fine.

Comment: You have provided very little information and no code. Please share more details to help

Comment: @ Arahasya When I manually install Release APK then it works fine but when same APK upload on Play Store then Problem Occurs. if the problem with code then there is a possibility that Debug and Release not working but there is no problem for that, then what happens with play store APK.

Comment: Try clearing app data and uninstall and install again